# My c++ string function does not run

Tags: c++, string

I have a simple c++ program that has a function to return a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    /// Some Code;
    string text= converter (i);
    /// Some more code

}
string converter(int number)
{
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                return "one";
                break;
            case 2:
                return "two";
                break;      
            default:
                cout << "Invalid";
        }
}
```

When i try to compile this i get the following error..

```
  error C3861: 'converter': identifier not found
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: could you show your complete code?

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. This cannot be answered without it.

Comment: Your function does not return a value in all execution paths. How does this code even compile?

Comment: You have undefined behavior in the `default:` case. `converter` has to return a string.

Comment: @barakmanos Because flowing off a non-void function is undefined behaviour, not an ill-formed program. Decent compilers warn about it, but it's legal. Simply because sometimes, proving that execution can/can't flow off would be beyond the capability of normal analysis.

Comment: Oh... sorry, it doesn't even compile: "when i try to run this i get the following error". You mean, when you try to compile it doesn't compile. Declare `string converter(int number)` before you call this function.

Comment: The problem could be in any part you have omitted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must declare the function before it may be used so the compiler can find it.

```
string converter(int number);
```

Comment: Blow. This was it. im returning to c++ after a gap of 12 years.

Comment: So that the compiler can find it. The linker has nothing to do with it, unless you call this function from a different source file (and even then, the compiler still has to "know about it").

Comment: He still has one more problem.

Comment: brain fart. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, you need a declaration like 
`string converter(int number);`
at the beginning of the file (e.g. after using namespace std;) or in a seperate and included header file.

Even if you solved your declaration problem, you will run into another:
Since you don't return anything in the switchs' default case you need to return something there or the compiler will say something about uncomplete controll paths and the program might run into undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Add a declaration of the function before you use it.

```
std::string converter(int);
```

Answer (score 1):

Either do as other answer suggests or simply cut your function code and paste it just below

```
using namespace std;
```

that's it....

Have a nice Day...